# I keeping the error "'std::logic_error' what(): basic_string::_M_construct null not valid" when i am trying to execute my code

Tags: c++

I am making a cypher code and when I am trying to execute it I get the "std::logic_error'   what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid". what is wrong with the code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
string cipher(int key,string text);
string decipher(int key,string text);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   string type;
   string text;
   string dtext;
   char* key1;
   int key;
   string s = argv[1];

   if (argc != 2) {
       cout << "Usage ./ceaser key" << endl;
       return 1;
   }

   else {
        for (int k = 0;k < s.length(); k++) {

           if (isalpha(argv[1][k]))
           {
               cout << "Usage: ./caesar key" << endl;
               return 1;
           }
           else
           {
               continue;
           }
       }

   }
   cout << "Type c for cipher and d for decipher: ";
   cin >> type;
   cout << "text: ";
   getline(cin, text);

   key1 = argv[1];
   key = atoi(key1);
   if (type == "c") {
      cipher(key,text);
   }
   else {
       decipher(key,text);
   }
   cout << endl;


}

string cipher(int key,string text) {
     for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        if (islower(text[i])) {
            char m = (((text[i] + key) - 97) % 26) + 97;
            cout << m;
        }
        else if(isupper(text[i])){
            char a = (((text[i] + key) - 65) % 26) + 65;
            cout << a;
        } 

        else {
            cout << text[i];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

string decipher(int key,string text) {
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
         if (islower(text[i])) {
            char m = (((text[i] - key) - 97) % 26) + 97;
            cout << m;
        }
        else if(isupper(text[i])){
             char a = (((text[i] - key) - 65) % 26) + 65;
             cout << a;
        }

        else {
           cout << text[i];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How can I fix this, it worked fine when I only made it a cypher but not decipher. but when I try to decipher it stopped working.

Comment: Be a good idea to move the `if (argc != 2)` block ahead of `string s = argv[1];`. Really suck if the program failed on the line before the check to make sure it doesn't fail.

Comment: Side note: prefer `'a'`  to `97`. The purpose of `'a'` is immediately obvious to readers and the code ha s a better chance of porting to other encodings.

Comment: Pretty sure the problem is [Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction), but I can't prove it at the moment

Comment: OK, The above's not the problem, but it is a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string cipher(int key,string text) {
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

a return statement applies the appropriate constructor of the return type, if the returned value is not of the correct type. In this case `std::string::string(const char*)` is used and the null pointer is passed causing the issue. You need to return the result of the encryption here instead of printing the result to stdout. (Proceed accordingly in `decypher`.)

In this case contrary to my comment you may actually pass the value by copy to be able to modify the string and return it:

```
...
if (islower(text[i])) {
    //char m = (((text[i] + key) - 97) % 26) + 97;
    //cout << m;
    text[i] = (((text[i] + key) - 97) % 26) + 97;
}

...
return text;
```

Comment: Smurf. Totally missed that. I'm going to bed. The brain's clearly switched off.

Comment: It worked there r no errors but I am not able to give the text input which needs to deciphered or cyphered I will try to figure that out. thank you for your help